# Store an array of elements to database (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need advice how to store an array to database. For example i have an input with `name="user_phone[]"` and i want to store to database the value of this input.
I have a form like so, also there other inputs but i copy just one:

```
{!! Form::open([route('some.router')]) !!}

 <fieldset class="form-group">
   {{ Form::label(null, 'Phone') }}
     {{ Form::text('user_phone[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control'] ) }}
 </fieldset>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

and the controller:

```
public function postAddOrder(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'receipt_date' => 'date|required',
            'return_date' => 'date|required',
            'user_name' => 'required',
            'user_phone' => 'required',
            'work_sum' => 'integer|required',
            'user_descr' => 'required',
            'foruser_descr' => 'required'
        ]);

        $user = new User;
        $user = $user->all()->find($request->input('user_name'));

        $order = new Order([
            'receipt_date' => $request->input('receipt_date'),
            'return_date' => $request->input('return_date'),
            'user_name' => $user->fio,
            'user_phone' => $request->input('user_phone'),
            'device' => $request->input('device'),
            'work_sum' => $request->input('work_sum'),
            'master_name' => $request->input('master_name'),
            'user_descr' => $request->input('user_descr'),
            'foruser_descr' => $request->input('foruser_descr'),
            'type' => $request->input('type'),
            'status' => $request->input('status'),
            'engineer' => $request->input('engineer'),
            'partner' => $request->input('partner'),
            'office' => $request->input('office')
        ]);

        $order->save();

        return redirect()->route('admin.orders.index');

    }
```

The problem is when i'm submitting the form and getting the error:

```
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

Also i'm using casts to store an array to DB:

```
/**
     * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'user_phone' => 'array',
    ];
```

The values are storing correctly, the main problem is that the validate() method is not catching the errors. For example im not filling some data in inputs which are required. When instead of getting the error like something is required im getting error

```
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

When im filling all input with data everything goes ok.

Comment: you can use php's `implode` function and store comma separated values into database..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the definition.

```
{!! Form::open([route('some.router')]) !!}

 <fieldset class="form-group">
   {{ Form::label(null, 'Phone') }}
     {{ Form::text('user_phone[0]', null, ['class' => 'form-control'] ) }}
 </fieldset>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

We must pass the index in inputs. Like `name="user_phone[0]"` after that we are not getting the error:

```
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

And `validate()` method catching the errors. It was the only solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem comes from your rule

```
'user_phone' => 'required
```

To validate array values you should use the array validation. ([Link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#validating-arrays))

rewrite your rule like so

```
"user_phone.0" => "required"
```

this will ensure that at least one user_phone is provided.

In case you wanna validate phone format just go with:

```
"user_phone.*" => "{Insert validation here}"
```

Comment: `{{ Form::text('user_phone[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control'] ) }}` is it true to have an input like this?? with this brackets to store array of values? or  maybe there is another way in laravel?

Comment: No problem with that.
Did you identify if the error comes at validation or during order creation ?

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/d4a83e7d3b2f480339c97c0e0ca4bf90.png - maybe it helps. I dont really know. I think the errors comes before validation. Because im getting error right after the submitting form

Comment: Also I just realised the section were you select the user should be something like that:
$user = User::find($request->input('user_name'));

Comment: I'm wondering if the saving part is actually fine(check if you have new rows in DB), the error seems to happen when rendering your view "admin.orders.index". Check how do you use the user_phone field in the view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123539/discussion-between-hyti-and-pwnz22).

Comment: If im filling all the inputs in my form the data is storing and im getting the right view. All info displaying fine. But if im not filling even one input im getting this error